# How can I simulate an offline iOS device when using XCTest (in Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, xctest

How would I go about simulating an offline iOS device using XCTest (in Swift preferably) i.e. I have code which posts to CoreData and also does a HTTP post with some JSON data and I want to ensure that conditional logic works correctly when no internet connection is available.

Comment: One standard approach would be to mock the HTTP operations to return a failure condition. See OCMock and friends. (Although admittedly, the outlook for Swift and OCMock is less than wonderful: http://ocmock.org/swift/ )

Comment: Try use network conditioner, you can download it from Apple developer website

Comment: Simulating offline is easy by pulling the network plug :-)